# WSO2 Identity Server Configure Pool in Custom user store management

Tags: wso2, database-connection, wso2-identity-server

I am using class **CustomUserStoreManager extends UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager** for user authentication . Sometimes db pool exhasted (because default pool size)

please tell how to set db pool configuration in identity server for custom user store?

I have tried but below link but it didn't gave complete details

[WSO2 Identity Server - Custom JDBC User Store Manager - JDBC Pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398071/wso2-identity-server-custom-jdbc-user-store-manager-jdbc-pools)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option `maxActive` to the userdb DB configs in your `deployment.toml`. Take a look at the following. Reference [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/change-to-mssql/).

```ini
[database.shared_db.pool_options]
maxActive = "80"
maxWait = "360000"
minIdle ="5"
testOnBorrow = true
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit=false
commitOnReturn=true
```

**Update**
I misread your question, above is when using the default userstore. How to set the connection pool depends on how you have implemented the `CustomUserStoreManager`. Where ever you are creating the connection pools in the user-store manager you will have to set the pool size accordingly.